# How do we interpret this indexing?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I came across the following Python script:

```
import numpy

image = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
image_padded = numpy.zeros((image.shape[0] + 2, image.shape[1] + 2))
image_padded[1:-1, 1:-1] = image
```

I understand that the last statement would equal to the 3x3 image array. The part I couldn't understand is how the indexing was made: `[1:-1, 1:-1]`. How can we interpret what this indexing is doing?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)?

Comment: Bad code, btw.  They should use `np.pad`.

Comment: @wim, But internally `np.pad` does this same thing - in 4 steps.  It does the pre and post pad separately 1 dimension at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [45]: 
    ...: image = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
    ...: image_padded = numpy.zeros((image.shape[0] + 2, image.shape[1] + 2))
    ...:
```

`1:-1` is a slice excluding the outer 2 items.  It starts with `1`, and ends before the last `-1`:

```
In [46]: image[1:,:]
Out[46]: 
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [47]: image[:-1,:]
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [48]: image[1:-1,:]
Out[48]: array([[4, 5, 6]])
```

Same applies to the 2d indexing.

```
In [49]: image_padded[1:-1, 1:-1]
Out[49]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
In [50]: image_padded[1:-1, 1:-1] = image
In [51]: image_padded[1:-1, 1:-1]
Out[51]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [7., 8., 9.]])
In [52]: image_padded
Out[52]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 0.],
       [0., 4., 5., 6., 0.],
       [0., 7., 8., 9., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Adjacent differences are taken with expressions like `image[1:] - image[:-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)
    
    `a[start:end] # items start through end-1
    a[start:]    # items start through the rest of the array
    a[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1
    a[:]         # a copy of the whole array`

and -1 means the last element, so: from 1 to the last element of the two dimension.